# Mongoose use array in find().where()

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of Strings that I want to use as a parameter for finding documents in my mongodb.

Basically what I want to do is

```
// Using query builder
Person.
  find().
  where('name.last').equals('Ghost' || 'ETC' || 'ETC')....
```

But instead of using a bunch of or statements, I want to just pass my array of Strings.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.in` method, taking `$in` operator in play:

```
Person.
  find().
  where('name.last').in(['Ghost', 'Foo', 'Bar'])
```

Quoting [the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

> The `$in` operator selects the documents where the value of a field
>   equals any value in the specified array.